# How to delete rows in DataFrame based on time intervals in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very large DataFrame consisting of time values. I want to delete the rows that are less than a minute apart, how would I go about doing that?

[Note: These are readings from a machine taken for 60 minutes thus the dataframe is much larger than the picture, the 27.2 eventually changes as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pay8D.png)

I tried using newdf=df1[df1['Time'].dt.minute%1==0] hoping it would delete every row that wasn't at least a minute apart but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from @Stu Sztukowski removes adjacent rows which are less than 1m apart, which may be what you want. But it could result in very long periods between retained values if each removed row was a small time after the previous (as in your data). So much data would be lost. Below is an alternative approach which retains rows which are more than 1m from the **previous retained**  row.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'time': ["2020-07-07 17:13:25", "2020-07-07 17:13:47", "2020-07-07 17:14:35", "2020-07-07 17:14:55"],
                   'val': [1, 2, 3, 4]
                   })

df['time']=pd.to_datetime(df['time'])


start = df.loc[0, 'time'] - pd.Timedelta('1m')
                       
def func(x):
    global start
    if (x-start) < pd.Timedelta('1m'):
        return False
    else:
        start = x
        return True
    
df2 = df[df['time'].map(func)]

print(df)
print(df2)
```

which gives:

```
                 time  val
0 2020-07-07 17:13:25    1
1 2020-07-07 17:13:47    2
2 2020-07-07 17:14:35    3
3 2020-07-07 17:14:55    4
                 time  val
0 2020-07-07 17:13:25    1
2 2020-07-07 17:14:35    3
```

Answer (score 0):

Subtract the two rows from each other and compare to a 1 minute time delta.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': ['2020-7-7 21:00:00', 
                            '2020-7-7 21:00:30', 
                            '2020-7-7 21:01:30']})

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

df_new = df[ ~(df['time'] - df['time'].shift() < pd.Timedelta('1m')) ]
```

```
                 time
0 2020-07-07 21:00:00
2 2020-07-07 21:01:30
```